# Define Controller for the custom action doesnot seem to work Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

HI Everyone ,

I have rails admin implemented in my project Now there are couple of thing that I currently stuck at

1. I want a link (Mark as Publisher) In the list View of my user Controller in the rails admin as ajax link something that is done using **remote => true** in rails after that where the write the associated jscode and html code for it
2. for the above custom action "**mark_as_publisher**" I define the configuration setting like this

   Inside **config/rails_admin.rb**

   ```
    config.actions do 

           # root actions
         dashboard                     # mandatory
         # collection actions 
         index                         # mandatory
         new
         export
         history_index
         bulk_delete
         # member actions
         show
         edit
         delete
         history_show
         show_in_app
         member :mark_as_publisher
    end
   ```

   Now The Definition of the custom action look like this

   ```
   require "rails_admin_mark_as_publisher/engine"

   module RailsAdminMarkAsPublisher
   end

   require 'rails_admin/config/actions'

   module RailsAdmin
     module Config
       module Actions
         class MarkAsPublihser < Base
           RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

           register_instance_option :collection do
             true
           end

           register_instance_option :http_methods do
             [:get,:post]
           end

           register_instance_option :route_fragment do
             'mark_as_publisher'
           end 

           register_instance_option :controller do
             Proc.new do
               binding.pry
               if request.get?
                 respond_to do |format|
                   format.html { render @action.template_name} 
                 end
               elsif request.post?
                 redirect_path = nil
                 if @object.update_attributes(:manager => true)
                   flash[:success] = t("admin.flash.successful", :name => @model_config.label, :action => t("admin.actions.mark_as_publisher.done"))
                   redirect_path = index_path
                 else
                   flash[:error] = t("admin.flash.error", :name => @model_config.label, :action => t("admin.actions.mark_as_publisher.done"))
                   redirect_path = back_or_index
                 end
               end  
             end
           end  
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Now the View for the same define in **app/view/rails_admin/main/mark_as_publisher.erb**  look like this

```
<%=  rails_admin_form_for @object, :url => mark_as_publisher_path(:model_name => @abstract_model.to_param, :id => @object.id), :as => @abstract_model.param_key,:method => :post ,:html => { :class => "form-horizontal denser", :data => { :title => "Mark" } } do |form| %>
  <%= form.submit "save" %>
<%end%>
```

The get and post url for mark_as_publisher does come under by controller define above and saving the above form result in error called

`could not find routes for '/user/5/mark_as_publisher' :method => "post"`

Does Any body has an idea of what I'm missing

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delayed reply, but I also came into the exact same issue.

EDIT: I notice you already have this, have you tried restarting your server?

if you add the following it will fix it.

```
  register_instance_option :http_methods do
      [:get,:post]
  end
```

The problem is by default `Actions` only respond to the :get requests.

If you run

```
 rake routes
```

You will see something along the lines of

```
  mark_as_publisher_path     GET     /:model_name/:id/mark_as_publisher(.:format)    rails_admin/main#mark_as_publisher
```

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/base.rb#L89